# Maps between groups and classifying spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose we have two Lie groups $G$ and $H$, as well as two homomorphisms $\phi_1,\phi_2 \colon G \to H$ and an arbitary continuous map $g \colon G \to G$. Futhermore suppose that $\phi_2$ is homotopic to $\phi_1\circ g$.

Is there a map $G \colon BG \to BG$ such that $B\phi_2$ is homotopic to $B\phi_1 \circ G$ ?